# Deploying Node.js App Using Heroku & GitHub

Tags: node.js, express, github, heroku, deployment

I've currently been spending hours trying to resolve some runtime errors that I am having when trying to launch my heroku app.  I'm attached my logs, file structure, package.json file, and Procfile as reference.  I know that I am missing something but I can identifty what it is. Any help in the matter would be appreciated, I didn't think I would run into so many issues using Heroku.

[image]
Here is my file structure ->

```
{
  "name": "pokedex-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cjs-loader": "^0.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "google-auth-library": "^7.6.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "7.x"
  }
}

2021-08-14T15:06:07.769961+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user berriosa13@gmail.com
2021-08-14T15:06:08.010780+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-08-14T15:06:11.223810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903922+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903938+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903939+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903939+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903939+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903939+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903939+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903940+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903940+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903940+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)    
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903941+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903941+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:1)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903941+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)  
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903941+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903942+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)       
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903942+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903943+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903943+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903943+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-08-14T15:06:12.903944+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-08-14T15:06:12.960936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-14T15:06:13.073784+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-08-14T15:06:54.527085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=anthonys-pokedex.herokuapp.com request_id=8bae5904-9302-4244-9b58-ab87ddb462b8 fwd="73.165.31.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-14T15:06:54.895843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=anthonys-pokedex.herokuapp.com request_id=f3fad693-09d3-441d-8ef6-4af197454c4a fwd="73.165.31.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow this tutorial:
This worked for me.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-nodejs-app-to-heroku-from-github-without-installing-heroku-on-your-machine-433bec770efe/

> **How to deploy a NodeJS app to Heroku from Github (without installing Heroku on your machine):**
> In this demo, we will be looking at how to deploy your cool NodeJS app to Heroku. By the end of this demo, we will have a basic Hello World app running on a public domain that can be accessed by anyone.

Comment: Thank you I'll definitely check it out, I have seen a couple other tutorials but they have all seemed to be different.

Comment: They are many different tutorials. But I tried like 6 tutorials and this was the tutorial that worked.

Comment: I'm having trouble with my error messages specifically with my env file :/

Comment: Try remaking the env file and uploading it manually